# Funny Latin book about etymology and grammar

Tags: etymology, resource-request

Are there funny Latin books about the etymology of words, like *Word Perfect* by Susie Dent for English etymology, or *Have You Eaten Grandma?* by Gyles Brandreth for English grammar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Amo, Amas, Amat… And All That: How to Become a Latin Lover* by Harry Mount (London, Short Books, 2006)** fits the bill; the writing is also in the Dent/Brandreth school of erudite but popular-audience, gently comic British writing and, flicking through my old copy which I haven't read in years, it certainly talks about Latin grammar as well as literature and history.